# Processing a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists, say:

```
    arr = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
```

I would like to append 100 to each of the inner lists. Output for the above example would be:

```
    arr = [[1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 100], [1, 4, 100]]
```

I can of course do:

```
    for elem in arr:
        elem.append(100)
```

But is there something more pythonic that can be done? Why does the following not work:

```
    arr = [elem.append(100) for elem in arr]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your code also works - the only thing you have to know is that there is no need to assign result to variable in such a case:

```
arr = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
[x.append(100) for x in arr]
```

After execution arr will contain updated list [[1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 100], [1, 4, 100]], e.g it work like in-place update, but this not very common practice to do this.

The same result you will get in the next case:

```
map(lambda x: x.append(100), arr)
```

As was discussed you can use list comprehension or map to do this with assigning result to any variable:

```
res = map(lambda x: x + [100], arr)
```

Comment: The first two aren't idiomatic, and the second doesn't even work in Python 3.

Comment: Sorry if so, but i notified OP about first two cases. The third one was not tested in python 3 since i have never worked with it. Thank you for notifying me about this.

Answer (score 5):

The second version should be written like `arr = [elem + [100] for elem in arr]`. But the most pythonic way if you ask me is the first one. The `for` construct has it's own use, and it suits very well here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
[a + [100] for a in arr]
```

The reason why your `append` doesn't work is that `append` doesn't return the list, but rather `None`.

Of course, this is more resource intensive than just doing `append` - you end up making copies of everything.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out why the append in my example does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is the more pythonic way

```
 for elem in arr:
     elem.append(100)
```

but as an option you can also try this:

```
[arr[i].append(100) for i in range(len(arr))]
print arr # It will return [[1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 100], [1, 4, 100]]
```